# How to get clone a record without use standard clone button

Tags: apex, trigger

```
public void noRelationClone(sObject record, boolean preserveID, 
                            boolean preserveReadOnlyTimestamps, boolean preserveAutonumber)
{
    sObject recordClone = record.clone(preserveID, false, 
                                       preserveReadOnlyTimestamps, preserveAutoNumber);
    for(Schema.sObjectField field : recordClone.getSObjectType().getDescribe()
                                                                .fields.getMap().values())
    {
        if (field.getDescribe().getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Reference)
        {
            recordClone.put(field, null);
        }
    }
    return recordClone;
}
```

Comment: what the issue you are facing?

Comment: Please add more details to your original post.  See the [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the `.clone` method is to clone the fields on the record specified.  It is going to clone the fields that you have access to when you called the record clone.. Which means the fields that you queried when you retrieved the record.  If you want to clone all of the fields, in the manner in which you are trying to (after you have called your record.clone), you will need to create a way to get all the fields prior to calling the clone method.  I have done it before with a dynamic query building the query fields much like you are in you portion of code..  you are just doing it after the fact.

For example:  If you query a record from Accounts like below, only Name will get cloned leaving the rest of the creatable fields blank.

```
Account a = [SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 1];
Account a2 = a.clone();
```

Comment: Hi JRiffe, can you please share all the logic of clone functionality because I am a beginner.

Comment: @jitendrapal Hi, can you update your answer with the changes that you have made that I have suggested?  Then, perhaps we can go from there.